# Django doesn't put /media/ in front of image url outside of admin section

Tags: python, django

In the admin area of Django, the image is well served because django automatically puts '/media/' in front of the image url.

But in the public part of my website, when I do this :

```
 <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ article.image_desc }}" alt="Card image cap">
```

The image is not. served because the url is not complete.

How to easily fix this issue ? I could do this :

```
 <img class="card-img-top" src="/media/{{ article.image_desc }}" alt="Card image cap">
```

But it's not convenient at all.

Comment: try with {{ article.image_desc.url }}

Comment: It was just the answer !! thanks dude !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `{{ article.image_desc }}` Django is not getting the full path of the image.

To fix that you should just do the following:

```
{{ article.image_desc.url }}
```

Also, you need to have the following in the `settings.py`:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'data/') # 'data' is my media folder
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```